# Django issue with linking css to html

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am aware that there are other posts on this, however, none of the answers have helped fix my issue.
I am making a django project and would like to use some basic css on my page, however it does not seem to be linking. The html file is in a folder called templates, while the css is in a folder called static.
Here is what I used to link my css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src='../static/style.css'>
```

And my css file looks like this:

```
body {
  background: black;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The method you used is for only connecting HTML to CSS normally but
in your case your code should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="{% static 'path/to/file/'  %}">
```

and don't forget to put `{% load static %}` at the top of your file.
Note: the 'path/to/file' should start from within the static dir.
Example: For a file structure like this:

```
|--static
|  |-- css
|      |-- styles.css
```

Your link should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
```